# Translating “Woe be to those…”

Tags: word-choice, translation, syntax

I'm trying to say this in Japanese: "Woe be to those who near the swamp."

I wasn't really sure how to go about this, but I came up with this:

> それらのための災いは誰が沼に行きます
>   *Woe for those who go to the swamp.*

Is this correct at all? I'm very unsure about this sentence. Perhaps there's a better way of saying this?

Comment: I'd say something more like `沼に近寄る者は不幸である`.

Comment: Perhaps: 「沼に近づく人々に災いがあるように」。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match the tone of "woe" and the slightly older sounding English of the original, why not?

> 沼地に近寄る者に災いあれ

Your

> それらのための災いは誰が沼に行きます

Is, I'm sorry to say, mostly nonsensical: "disasters for the benefit of those, who goes to the swamp?"